# Problems With List

Tags: c#

I have a problems with String[], i want to make a programming language. and if you know good compiler design tutorials with examples in C# that will be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/tut.txt");
        String data = reader.ReadLine();

        String[] tok;

        foreach(char s in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            tok.add(s); // error
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahem, and the question is?

Comment: `String[]` is array and not dynamic list. If you need a list, define it like `List<string> tok`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic first subsection, item 4:Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Tigran you also need to instantiate it.  `List<string> tok = new List<string>()`

Comment: You can read Niklaus Wirth's (tiny) book [Compiler Construction (PDF)](http://www.ethoberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf) as an introduction to the theory and the techniques of compiler construction. It gives you a general idea of what a compiler is and what it does. I also would have a look at complier compliers. [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/) is a .NET complier compiler that lets you define the syntax of a langue using C# constructs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish...maybe this?

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/tut.txt");
        String data = reader.ReadLine();

        List<String> tok = new List<string>();

        foreach (char s in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            tok.Add(s.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Seems like `tok` would be better as a `List<char>`